# How to hide reports from print menu in odoo 14?

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-14

i created a report in odoo 14 but i want to trigger only from button **so i want to hide from print menu** ....

```
<record id="report_export_sale_order" model="ir.actions.report">
    <field name="name">Print Packing List</field>
    <field name="model">sale.order</field>
    <field name="report_type">qweb-pdf</field>
    <field name="report_name">sales_enhancement.report_export_so</field>
    <field name="report_file">sales_enhancement.report_export_so</field>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_sale_order"/>
    <field name="binding_type">report</field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it will hide by adding modify "binding_model_id" to False

```
<field name="binding_model_id" eval="False"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the report from the print menu using the `Remove from the 'Print' menu` button in the report form view which calls the `unlink_action` to set the [binding_model_id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/14.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions_report.py#L178) to `False`.

Answer (score 2):

For people who are using the report shortcut tag, you can use `menu="False"` attribute. This worked at least in previous Odoo versions:

```
<report id="action_report_custom
        string="Report"
        model="sale.order"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        file="custom_module.report_custom"
        name="custom_module.report_custom"
        print_report_name="'Report Custom - %s' % (object.name)"
        menu="False" />
```

Comment: This answer is the correct answer, the trick in "menu="False" "

Answer (score 1):

in odoo 15 it will hide using this:

```
<field name="binding_model_id"></field>
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the
menu="False"
in your report tag